# Доработать метод на сортировку String массива

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

помогите пожайлуста доработать метод, чтобы он сортировал не int, а String массивы.
ShellSort - этот метод называется. Если в общем по коду более-менее понятно, то в строке for `(j = i; j >= gap && arr[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap)` не могу понять как переписать.

```
 int sort(int arr[]) 
        { 
            int n = arr.length; 
                for (int i = gap; i < n; i += 1) { 
                    int temp = arr[i]; 
                    int j; 
                    for (j = i; j >= gap && arr[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap) 
                        arr[j] = arr[j - gap]; 
                    arr[j] = temp; 
                } 
            } 
            return 0; 
        }
```

Comment: а сортировка массивов из коробки с помощью , например Arrays.sort (), чем вас не устраивает?

Comment: @  устраивает меня, но задание другое, иначе бы не писал)

Comment: так для того, чтобы доработать метод, который должен сортировать не int, а String массивы, нужен сначала метод, который сортирует int массивы, а ваш код даже не скомпилируется хотя бы потому, что переменная gap взялась непонятно откуда, да и единственная инструкция возврата в виде  return 0 не создает видимость рабочего метода для сортировки

Comment: @Дмитрий именно поэтому я сюда и пишу, что мне нужен подобный метод только на стринг.. Мне и самому понятно, что int и String это разные вещи.. на ретерн можно не смотреть, главное что операторы рабочие... Если нужен полный код, то я могу его сюда скинуть, но не знаю позволены ли тут ссылки иных сайтов..

Comment: @Дмитрий метод ранее был создан на сортировку int массивов.

Comment: это никак не противоречит тому, что я написал. метод не работает для интов

Comment: @Дмитрий потому-что частично переделан на String мной, а там где не понял загрузил сюда.. Ибо Shell Sort должны знать все опытные прогреры и не только..  Код исходный тут https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shellsort/

Comment: мне сейчас интересно, вы действительно считаете, что все программисты обязательно должны выучит наизусть кусок кода на приведенном вами сайте и распознавать его по фрагменту, в том числе неудачно переделанному?))

Comment: @Дмитрий Если Вы учили алгоритмы, что по сути входит в обучение по  специальности, которую Вы скорее всего учили, чтобы стать тем, кем Вы есть сейчас. Иначе как тогда работать с большими обьемами данных не понимая как оно работает изнутри? Разумеется готовые методы не учитывая, а их в универах не учитывают. 2 - Перечитайте еще раз тему прежде чем писать, там ключевые слова - "ПОМОГИТЕ", "ДОРАБОТАТЬ", "НЕ МОГУ ПОНЯТЬ КАК ПЕРЕПИСАТЬ". Это бы ответило Вам на многие вопросы. Если Вы не можете помочь, то давайте прекратим дискуссию, она не к чему.. мне нужна помощь, а не разговоры...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class ShellSort {

    int sort(String arr[]) {
        for (int gap = arr.length / 2; gap > 0; gap /= 2) {
            for (int i = gap; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
                final String temp = arr[i];
                int j;
                for (j = i; j >= gap && arr[j - gap].compareTo(temp) > 0; j -= gap) {
                    arr[j] = arr[j - gap];
                }
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String arr[] = {"xxx", "aaa", "ccc", "bbb", "zzz"};
        System.out.println("Array before sorting");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        ShellSort ob = new ShellSort();
        ob.sort(arr);

        System.out.println("Array after sorting");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Во-первых, дискуссия не бесполезная, она заставила вас дополнить вопрос ссылкой на код, который вы пытались переписать, что перевело вопрос из категории "битва экстрасенсов" в более адекватную рубрику. Во-вторых, я не увидел в вашем коде ничего нового, т.е. отличного от исходника на сайте (кроме того, что он скопирован не в полном объеме, что сде5лал его еще и нарабочим). Ну и последнее, задача тривиальнее некуда, потому как для алгоритма сортировки не имеет никакого значения, с какими данными работать, следовательно все, что нужно изменить - сигнатуры методов (чтобы они принимали String вместо int), а также поменять оператор сравнения для arr[j - gap]>temp, который сравнивает int, на метод compareTo, сравнивающий String.  Еще можно убрать метод печати массива, поскольку для ссылочных типов такой метод уже написан и достается из коробки. А раз задача такая тривиальная, я все пытался выяснить, что же вы дорабатывали и не смогли доработать, т.е. какое именно из 2 слов так и не удалось заменить:  > на compareTo или int на String? но в любом случае желание разобраться - это уже хорошо, посему удачи в изучении Java)

Comment: А я уже подумал, что Вы тролите) Да именно эту часть кода(arr[j - gap]>temp) я не понял, когда при замене int на String вышла ошибка и поэтому скопировал всю строку cюда с вопросом. Огромнейшее спасибо.

Comment: @Str не за что, удачи)